# SaveAs method error

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting a 'Method 'SaveAS' of object '_Workbook' failed, I can't for the life of me figure out why. Code below... any recommendation unrelated to the initial question are welcome!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Declarations
    'The two workbooks to be involved
    Dim SourceWB As Workbook
    Dim DestinationWB As Workbook

'values to contain cell data to be copied across the worksheet
Dim systemName As Variant
Dim systemID As Variant
'Counter variable to allow for the loop
Dim counter As Integer

'Set the source workbook equal to the current workbook
Set SourceWB = ActiveWorkbook

For counter = 1 To 5

'Set the values for the two data values to be copied
     systemName = SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value
     systemID = SourceWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 2).Value
'Open the destination Workbook
    Set DestinationWB = Workbooks.Open("Path to workbook")
'Set destination cells equal to the copied data from the source sheet
    DestinationWB.Sheets("Questionnaire").Cells(7, 3).Value = systemName
    DestinationWB.Sheets("Questionnaire").Cells(8, 3).Value = systemID
    'Set fname to save Destination Workbook
    Fname = "H:\Desktop\Automated Questionnaires to send\" & systemName & " Applicability Questionnaire.xlsm"
'Save the Destination workbook
    DestinationWB.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=52
    DestinationWB.Close    
Next counter


End Sub
```

Comment: you are missing the fileformat property

Comment: @ShaiRado I made the changes but without any luck, still getting the same error

Comment: What is the value of `Fname` when it fails?

Comment: Or... more importantly, what is the value of `systemName` when it fails. Are you able to "save as" to that path manually? does that path exist already or do you need to [create that directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1d22wfh(v=vs.90).aspx) first before saving?

Comment: It is what I set it to above "H:\Desktop\Automated Questionnaires to send\" & systemName & " Applicability Questionnaire.xlsm"

Comment: systemName is what it should be... The file does get saved because I have the excel sheet pop up, fill out the fields, and then it saves, but then I get the error... But the workbook still has the appropriate file name...let me clarify that.... It has the filename in the title, it doesn't actually save it to the correct folder.